# How to remove right sidebar in magento 1.9

Tags: magento

I installed magento 1.9.

After installed widget and slieshow, my page look like this,

[image]

Here i want to remove recently viewed products and compare products.

So i removed in app/design/frontend/modern/layout/catalog.xml ,(these lines i removed)

```
    <block type="catalog/product_compare_sidebar" before="cart_sidebar" name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml"/>
```

But still stays sidebar.

can anyone help me?

Comment: Look for a block type with name something like `right`.. remove that block and you will be good.

Comment: @Mr_Green: Where i go to do this?

Comment: check in layout files.. `.xml`

Comment: @Mr_Green: In layout file , not have right.xml, only have rss and review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go to magento admin click on cms home page , click on design now select layout 1 column now save and refresh page

Comment: I have a one more doubt, I my slideshow setting, i adjust width and height, but still nothing seems to be change, what to do?

Comment: Find the Parent div of your slider then write class with height and width for that parent div. slider's height and width would be generating from js soo there is no benefit to fix height and width of that

Comment: may i know why don't change in common setting and position settings of magic slideshow.

Comment: yes you can change that if there is an option in admin for that. is there any option for height and width in admin > magic slidedshow settings

Comment: I changed width as 20px and height as 20px, but nothing happen

Answer (score 0):

To remove from Home Page to to Admin panel CMS/PAGES/Home Page then go to Design Tab there the first option is Layout. Change it to 1 column. SO it will change the layout of (only )Home Page to one column without left and right.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="MagicSlideshow" data-options="width: 400px; height:187px;">
```

use this code

Comment: are you still facing any problem??

Comment: use firebug is there any class with name MagicSlideshow??

Comment: may i know, what is firbug?.. I installed slideshow from this site, http://www.magictoolbox.com/

Comment: it's a fire fox pluging which developer use to see the layout styles with css and all
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/

Comment: did you find that div??

Comment: Use Profile and Find the path of that file
http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/magento/203-troubleshooting-magento/enabling-the-debug-profiler-in-magento

Comment: Ok i followed that link and i did. after that what i do?

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same problem, and was able to remove the compare block using xml.

In my situation, I did not want change to a 1-column layout because of what I've already done with the right-col layout.

**Solution**:

- Copy "**catalog.xml**" from **/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout** or **/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout** if you're using the new rwd theme.
- Go to line 55 and remove or comment out the entire `<reference name="right">` block:

  ```
  <reference name="right">
      <block type="catalog/product_compare_sidebar" before="cart_sidebar" name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml"/>
      <!--<block type="core/template" name="right.permanent.callout" template="callouts/right_col.phtml">-->
          <!--<action method="setImgSrc"><src>images/media/col_right_callout.jpg</src></action>-->
          <!--<action method="setImgAlt" translate="alt" module="catalog"><alt>Keep your eyes open for our special Back to School items and save A LOT!</alt></action>-->
      <!--</block>-->
  </reference>
  ```
- Go to line 178 (for rwd_default) or 165 (for base_default)  and remove or comment out the `<customer_account_index>` block of code:

  ```
  <customer_account_index>
  <reference name="right">
      <action method="unsetChild"><name>catalog.compare.sidebar</name></action>
  </reference>
  ```
- Save the file into your custom theme layout folder as "catalog.xml".

Answer (score 0):

You can unset the compare side bar in the layout file of your theme. I added a new file in 
/app/design/frontend/myTheme/layout/local.xml
where I unset the compare side bar using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
<default>
    <action method="unsetChild"><name>catalog.compare.sidebar</name></action>
</default>
</layout>
```

Don't edit the default files as they will get overwritten on update.